# Is there a way to prevent importing files from flutter framework in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

In a flutter project, I'm following n-tier architecture. Where in a layer I don't want to allow **importing** files from the flutter framework. Is there a way to **prevent importing files** from flutter or any other layer?

I don't want to allow writing

`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`

in my `data` and `domain` layer

Comment: you can just import file that you need. remove other one

Comment: You could make your data and domain layers separate, possibly private, pure Dart packages that simply do not depend on the Flutter SDK.

Comment: my other team mate continuing return widgets in provider, controller, I want to prevent it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is a bit old but I don't see any answers yet, so I thought to share with you what I've found regarding the subject.
There are several ways to enforce the imports in your Flutter project (I documented them in details [here](https://medium.com/@abdelkrim.bournane/architecture-enforcement-in-flutter-apps-5618823925b7)) :

1. Using private and public : This enforces types to be private to a file (or a library) and we can only leave what we want others to depend on as public.
2. Using packages and dart analyzer : This techniques leverages the use of dart packages inside flutter projects in order to encapsulate a set of types and classes together and only export what we want to export. We can then use `analysis_options.yaml` to enable linter rules that can be triggered when we don't respect package import and try to import things directly with relative paths.
3. Using external packages like [import_lint](https://github.com/kawa1214/import-lint), [dart_code_metrics](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_code_metrics), or [dart_arch_test](https://github.com/gustavo-hillesheim/dart_arch_test)